# How to play video one by one and play/pause when scroll listview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to play video which is on frontView, how to detect the view in `listView` and play when `getView` and pause when scrolled up. How to do this?

**This is my code.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    public static int currentItem;
    public static ArrayList<String> videoLIst;
    public static MediaController mediaController ;
    boolean pauseOnScroll = true;
    boolean pauseOnFling = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        videoLIst = new ArrayList<String>();
         mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this); 
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, videoLIst);
        // Set video link (mp4 format )
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                int lastVisibleRow = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();

                for(int i=firstVisibleRow;i<=lastVisibleRow;i++)
                {
                    //Write your code here(allocation/deallocation/store in array etc.)
                    System.out.println(i + "=" + listview.getItemAtPosition(i));
                    currentItem = (int) listview.getItemAtPosition(i);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<String> videoList;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> videoList) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.videoList = videoList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return videoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return videoList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

            VideoView video = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            TextView  txvvideo =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txvposition);

            txvvideo.setText("Video"+position);

            mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
            Log.d("video url inadapter:", ""+videoLIst.toString());
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoList.get(currentItem));
            video.setMediaController(mediaController);
            video.setVideoURI(uri);
            video.start();
            int pos;
            pos=video.getCurrentPosition();
//          if(pos == currentItem)
//          {
//              video.pause();
//          }
//          video.setMediaController(mediaController);
//          video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoList.get(position)));
//          video.start();
             return convertView;
        }

    }    

}
```

I want to stop video when It is invisible in `listview` when I scroll it up or down.

Comment: did you manage to a list view with the videos and scroll down with them?

Comment: I am managing videos in listview.

Comment: @NidhiDave Check this awesome library meant to do that you are seeking for along with maintaining performance [Video list auto playback made simple, specially built for RecyclerView](https://github.com/eneim/Toro)

Comment: @NidhiDave did you found any solution i have also facing same issue..

Answer (score 2):

Create a [RecyclerListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.RecyclerListener.html) and set it on ListView:

```
    listView.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
            VideoView videoView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            videoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    });
```

When the view is scrolled offscreen and becomes "invisible", the ListView will recycle it and you'll get the onMovedToScrapHeap() will be called.

Comment: within onCreate() after: listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: but this code not working I am still not able to stop video when I scroll listview.

Comment: I have used this code it is working but one problem is there one it stops invisible video then if it becomes visible it cant play it again how I do this? how I play It again when invisible video become visible.

Answer (score 0):

I started with your code above and then made quite a few changes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    public int mCurrentItem;
    public static ArrayList<String> sVideoList;
    static
    {
        sVideoList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sVideoList.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        sVideoList.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        sVideoList.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        sVideoList.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        sVideoList.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        sVideoList.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        sVideoList.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        sVideoList.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
    }

    public static MediaController mediaController ;
    boolean pauseOnScroll = true;
    boolean pauseOnFling = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, sVideoList);
        // Set video link (mp4 format )
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setRecyclerListener(new AbsListView.RecyclerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
                // Safety net
                VideoView videoView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
                videoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        });
        listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            private int mFirstVisibleRow = -1;
            private int mActiveItem = -1;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                if( mFirstVisibleRow != firstVisibleRow )
                {
                    mFirstVisibleRow = firstVisibleRow;

                    // Cancel the video of the previous active item
                    VideoView prevActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                    if( prevActiveVideoView != null )
                    {
                        prevActiveVideoView.pause();
                    }

                    // Start the video of the new active item
                    mActiveItem = mFirstVisibleRow + 1;
                    VideoView newActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                    if(newActiveVideoView != null)
                    {
                        newActiveVideoView.start();
                    }
                }
            }

            private VideoView getVideoViewForRow(int row)
            {
                int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                View rowView = listview.getChildAt(row-firstVisibleRow);
                return (rowView == null) ? null : (VideoView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            }

        });

    }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<String> videoList;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> videoList) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.videoList = videoList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return videoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return videoList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, null);

            VideoView videoView = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            TextView videoTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txvposition);

            // We setup the video here but we don't start it until the view is scrolled to
            videoTextView.setText("Video " + position);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoList.get(position));
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

And video_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvposition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of starting the video when the view is created, you wait to start it until it becomes active. Only one VideoView is allowed to become active at one time and when it stops being active it is paused. Currently it's coded so that the second visible VideoView on the screen is active.

It's not perfect code. i.e. as it's implemented now the first VideoView in listview will never have its video played. It does, however, solve the problem above and will help you iterate further.

Comment: I used this code but this code is not working listview hang totally but if I used this code with my adapter it works but only one problem is there I got sequence of item repeted and not in ascending sometimes how I solve this and also once invisible vedio stop to play When its become visible It cant play again how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems with this.

1. manage video playback. (use `textureView`)
2. which view in scrolled list is currently active.

try [this link](https://github.com/sanurag51/https-github.com-danylovolokh-VideoPlayerManager) and [this one](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429#.nfk1mqmvt) also